# wanting to set up proxy on selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, proxy

running the proxy though code below works fine, am able to test it with whatsismyip.com and httpbin.org/ip and comes back proxy ip but when i put the code into my script it wont work?
using it for twitter via selenium for scraping

code i use to test it alone works fine like this

```
   from seleniumwire import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
   from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

   proxy_username = 'fgrlkbxt'
   proxy_password = 'cs01nzezlfen'
   seleniumwire_options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': f'http://{proxy_username}:{proxy_password}@185.199.229.156:7492',
        'verify_ssl': False,
    },
   }

   driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options
   )
   driver.get('http://httpbin.org/ip')
   print(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').text)
```

code i use on my script

```
    from seleniumwire import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    proxy_username = 'fgrlkbxt'
    proxy_password = 'cs01nzezlfen'
    seleniumwire_options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': f'http://{proxy_username}:{proxy_password}@185.199.229.156:7492',
        'verify_ssl': False,
    },
    }
```

is my code wrong or something?

i checked with logging into my twitter account and not seeing any "New login alert" from twitter with the location of the proxy. used another proxy that was working

inside the script there are multiple accounts want all the accounts to go though the proxy

also using adspower to mask webrtc idk if that plays a part in this no not

proxy set up on selenium